# Is it possible to put a objects other than UIViews into a custom TableViewCell?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, uipagecontrol

I am trying to create a `UITableView` that has cells with PageControls in them, which would allow each cell to scroll sideways to different views... I am using the Apple `UIPageControl` project [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PageControl/Introduction/Intro.html) and basically trying to insert one of these PageControl objects into a `UITableViewCell`.

I am pretty new to iOS and I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around how to customize the cell the way I want to... the cells are still showing up as the default ones with a title label.

Could someone please help me or at least tell me if what I'm trying to do is possible? :)

Comment: Do you want just the scrolling functionality or the page control UI as well? If you could show us how you allocate your cells that'd be great.